# WCF REST Return JSON with 2 properties

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf

I have the following issue. I need to return JSON with 2 properties at start and the 1 property will have multiple values that gets read from a table. The other is just to return a code. Can you please guide me through the steps the return these 2 objects in one class instance. The JSON would need to look like this.

The `GetAllCustomersResult` and `FoundData` tags must be the 2 objects.

```
{
"GetAllCustomersResult": [
    {
        "City": "Kimberley",
        "CompanyName": "My Company",
        "CustomerID": "Mary"
    },
    {
        "City": "London",
        "CompanyName": "My Company",
        "CustomerID": "Delia"
    },
    {
        "City": "Miami",
        "CompanyName": "My Company",
        "CustomerID": "Haley"
    }
]
}
```

This is my code.

```
public class Service1 : IService1

  {
    public wsCustomer[] GetAllCustomers()
    {
        NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext();
        List<wsCustomer> results = new List<wsCustomer>()
        {
            new wsCustomer { CustomerID = "Mary", CompanyName = "My Company", City = "Kimberley" },
            new wsCustomer { CustomerID = "Delia", CompanyName = "My Company", City = "London" },
            new wsCustomer { CustomerID = "Haley", CompanyName = "My Company", City = "Miami" } 
        };



        return results.ToArray();
    }
    public string founddata()
    {
        string foundCust = "1";
        return foundCust;
    }

}

}
```

My operation contract:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle =       WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "getAllCustomers")]
    wsCustomer[] GetAllCustomers();
```

Comment: very unclear. What is your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the results in another class and return that one:

```
public class Results
{
    public wsCustomer[] Customers {get;set;}
    public int Result {get;set;}
}
```